nvim-dap breakpoints are always rejected for C++ debug
I've tried to use the nvim-dap for the C++ debugger, but the breakpoints are always ignored.
The lua script attached below is nvim-dap config, which I ensured this file is read. If someone faced this issue before or is familiar with nvim-dap, I would appreciate some help.
The workflow is

create main.cpp (test C++ script)

compile and run with F2

I set this keymap; vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<F2>', ":w<CR>:rightbelow vsp | terminal g++ -g % -o %< && ./%< <CR>i", { noremap = true, silent = true }


set breakpoints with Ctrl + b

vim.keymap.set('n', '<F5>', function() require('dap').continue() end)

The breakpoints  are displayed at the right of line numbers.



start debugging with F5

vim.keymap.set('n', '<F5>', function() require('dap').continue() end)


select main

path to executable: /path/to/main


all breakpoints are ignored and the process hit the final line.

The rejected mark ⚠️ are emerged instead of the breakpoints.



#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


int main(){
  int a,b,c,d;
  a = 3;
  b = 5;
  c = a + b;
  d = b - a;
  std::cout << "c = " << c << std::endl;
  std::cout << "d = " << d << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

return
-- nvim-dap
{
  "mfussenegger/nvim-dap",
  config = function()
    local dap = require('dap'),
    vim.fn.sign_define('DapBreakpoint', {text='', texthl='DapBreakpoint', linehl='', numhl=''}),
    vim.fn.sign_define('DapStopped', {text='➡️', texthl='DapStopped', linehl='DebugLineHL', numhl=''}),
    vim.fn.sign_define('DapBreakpointCondition', {text='', texthl='DapBreakpoint', linehl='', numhl=''}),
    vim.fn.sign_define('DapBreakpointRejected', {text='⚠️', texthl='DapBreakpoint', linehl='', numhl=''})
    dap.adapters.lldb = {
      type = 'executable',
      command = '/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/lldb-dap',
      name = 'lldb'
    }
    dap.configurations.cpp = {
      {
        name = 'Launch',
        type = 'lldb',
        request = 'launch',
        program = function()
          return vim.fn.input('Path to executable: ', vim.fn.getcwd() .. '/', 'file')
        end,
        cwd = '${workspaceFolder}',
        stopOnEntry = false,
        args = {},
      },
    }
  end
}

I followed almost everything this page;
https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap/wiki/Debug-Adapter-installation#ccrust-via-lldb-vscode
What I already confirmed are;

/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/lldb-dap in the config is correct.

lldb-dap --help is working



Have you built your binary with debug symbols? Can you stop the execution when using lldb from the command line?
